# Trying to understand an FTP connection setting

Tags: python, ssl, ftp

I'm going through a shell script that connects to an FTP server, and after reading some documentation on SSL, FTP, and SFTP, I'm still confused as to which connection type and setting was used.

The relevant part of the shell script:

```
lftp -u $USER,$PASS $HOST <<EOF
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ssl:verify-certificate no
cd $DIR
ls *.7z > $work/list
quit
EOF
```

Is this an FTP SSL connection? How do I tell if it's explicit or implicit?

I'm thinking of re-doing this in Python - would the standard library `ftplib` suffice for making this connection and getting the files?

Comment: Add `-d` switch and you will see.

Comment: Read about [python-secure-ftp-module](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-secure-ftp-module)